# APL Group characters shows different behaviour on null character

Tags: apl

I'm just starting with `APL2`. From the demos I can see, `'a' 'p' 'l'` merges to `apl`. I wanted to separate these into separate arrays, so I did something like this: `('a') ('p') ('l')`. This however still merges to `'apl'`. As another attempt, I tried: `('a') ('p') ('l') ('')` and was able to get the array segregation. What has happened? Also, what is `''`? I apologize for the impatience. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The letters of `'apl'` already *are* "separate" arrays, so you can operate on them independently without having to take any further action. For convenience, vectors (lists) of characters are displayed in a tight fashion with the letters immediately adjacent to each other. However, if any element of the vector is not a simple rank-0 (0-dimensional) letter, the APL system may switch to an alternative display form to make the structure a bit clearer.

`''` is simply an empty character vector (that is, a list of no letters). Appending it as a separate element at the end of your vector makes the overall structure deeper, necessitating a more complex display form. It may be clearer to understand `'a' 'p' 'l' ''` (no parentheses are necessary) as equivalent to `'apl',⊂''`. [Try it!](https://tryapl.org/?a=%27a%27%20%27p%27%20%27l%27%20%27%27%20%u2261%20%27apl%27%2C%u2282%27%27&run)

While JSON doesn't have scalar characters, it does have scalar numbers, so `'apl'` is like `[97,112,108]` and `'apl',⊂''` is like `[97,112,108,[]]`.

Comment: I looked up on '⊂' (enclose) operation. I guess, I need to understand 'rank', 'depth', 'scalar' first. I guess, study for weekend. APL is pretty amazing. I'll learn it. Thank you for answer. I shall revisit the 'enclose' part, once done.

Comment: @user2338150 I can recommend frequenting [The APL Orchard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard) to boost your studies. People are always there to answer questions, discuss matters, and give tips and tricks. It also has an APL bot which can evaluate statements and link to valuable resources.